# iOS 9 issues - GameCenter

Tags: game-center, ios9

Since iOS 9 errors are appearing in the console when opening the Game Center View Controller. I have created a bare bones sample project to help diagnose and isolate the issue. My bare bones View Controller contains a UIButton to open the Game Center, and my code is the following:

```
import UIKit
import GameKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in
            if let viewController = viewController {
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                print("(GameCenter) Player authenticated: \(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)")
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func openGameCenter(sender: AnyObject) {
        let gameCenter = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gameCenter.gameCenterDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(gameCenter, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When presenting the Game Center View Controller, I see the following errors in the console:

> 2015-09-21 11:03:41.530 GameCenterTest[1552:415921]  - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only
>   layer, will have no effect 2015-09-21 11:03:41.531
>   GameCenterTest[1552:415921]  - changing
>   property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
>   2015-09-21 11:03:41.532 GameCenterTest[1552:415921]  - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only
>   layer, will have no effect

When tapping on `Done` and closing the Game Center View Cotroller, I see the following error in the console:

> 2015-09-21 11:03:52.263 GameCenterTest[1552:416142] plugin
>   com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated

Comment: I have the same error, have you figured it out?

Comment: Nope! So far don't see any problems other than the console errors though.

Comment: I realized that it doesn't cause a crash for me, it's just a new error message. Not sure what it means.

Comment: the error message your getting when clicking done isn't an error, its just telling you that you closed Game Center.

Comment: Nick Pacini Is this a guess, or where do you get this information? It seems to me that if that were the case, the message would be "GameCenter closed." To me, "Plugin invalidated" sounds like closing the game center caused something to occur within Apple's frameworks that triggered this message.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm seeing similar problems